# How could I import the json data in wordpress posts

Tags: json, wordpress

Here is the json data of mine, I want to put them in the wordpress,  I can write a PHP script to read the json data and write them in the mysql table `wp_posts`,but what is better for me.And I know that.

The json data is something like blow:

```
[
{"url": "http://www.test.com/page/111.html", "art_title": ["title111"], "art_content": ["the article content111"]},
{"url": "http://www.test.com/page/222.html", "art_title": ["title222"], "art_content": ["the article content222"]}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `json_decode` your JSON data, loop over it and then use `wp_insert_post` to add the post into WordPress ([ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)).

**Note:** You'll need to boot WordPress in your file before you can use `wp_insert_post`, you can do this by including `wp-load.php` in your custom script.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be to programatically insert this json data into WordPress in a semantically correct way. The best way to do this would be to make your json Objects posts (or custom pot types if they don't fit into a normal posts parameters using something like Humanmades Custom-Meta-Boxes to add meta data or http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). Then you could insert your json data into the db through wp_insert_post() each as a new post (obviously doing validation before doing so to check if the post already exists). Let me know if need any other help or can elaborate on the issue so that I can give a better answer.